# VSTS continuous integration triggers not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm pretty sure this setup was working at one point for  us. I changed our builds a bit to reflect some operational changes and now the CI git branch trigger isn't working. I'm trying to get it so when a PR is merged into master it triggers the release build. I can trigger this build manually but not when submitting a PR to master from dev and then accepting the PR (on github).

Is anyone else having issues or know whats wrong?

[image]

Comment: What's the result if you try it with a new build definition?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I didn't even think about trying that. Once I added a new build with the same trigger, both of the builds were triggered on the next PR merge. Thank you so much. I don't know what was going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding an answer so this more visible. @starain-MSFT comment was the solution.

I added a new build with the same trigger and it fixed the other one not getting triggered. Then deleted the new build I had added and everything is working.

Comment: This has happened twice on our hosted agents.  We had to clone the build to fix the issue too.  Once the build definition was cloned, both the original and clone started building.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6936103/marina-msft

Comment: Just ran into the exact same problem. As soon as I cloned the build definition both started kicking off as expected based on the trigger configuration

Comment: Just to help provide a timeline - this issue is still active, and this solution still works

Comment: Ran into same issue this week, cloned the build definition and it got the triggers working again on the original one. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: To provide a timeline as well, this still holds up today in Feb 2019.

Comment: Hi I'm from the future in Dec 2019. This is still a problem. Disable and re-enable fixed it.

Comment: I also have the same issue, no cloning has worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Cloning my build definition didn't work, unfortunately, and neither did saving a trivial change to the build definition. Instead, I had to explicitly disable the CI trigger, save, then re-enable it and save it again. (Annoying, because I had to redefine all the rules.) But give it a try if the accepted answer doesn't do it for you.

I also wonder if adding a random branch to the triggering branches list, saving, then removing the random branch and saving again would work (and save you from having to redefine everything).

Comment: This worked for me. I found it easier then cloning the pipeline.

Comment: Neither disabling CI trigger, nor cloning pipeline worked for me when using "Other Git". Does anyone have other suggestions?