# Azure DevOps CI trigger is not working even though the setting is set

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been using Azure DevOps for a while now, and CI has been working great. I commit to my branch, and it kicks off a branch automatically.

This has all of the sudden just stopped working.

[image]

I have tried all of the ideas from this question: 
[VSTS continuous integration triggers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471377/vsts-continuous-integration-triggers-not-working)

But I cannot get it to trigger the build automatically.
Please help!

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I tried just about everything. The only thing that seemed to work was completely delete all my build configurations and re-create from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps CI trigger is not working even though the setting is set

Some times service event( https://status.dev.azure.com/ ) in Azure DevOps may cause this issue. Besides, if there is `[skip ci]` in commit message, the build will skip the CI trigger.

Check the document [Skipping CI for individual commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits) for some more details.

Besides, if it still does not work now, try to manually Queue a build, then commit to to your branch again and check if it works for you. If not, try to create a new build pipeline to check if still have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the fix was to **delete unwanted GitHub service connections in 'Project Settings'**. Multiple service connections using oauth and azure pipeline *to same GitHub account* was present. Once it is removed, pipelines were getting triggered automatically.